# Find an entry in a MongoDB collection with a Date constraint using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongoose to interact with MongoDB, and now I would like to `findOne` document in a collection that has a certain field and a particular constraint on another field.

Basically the first field `resetPasswordToken` must be equal to `req.params.token`, the second instead `resetPasswordExpires` should have a constraint, which is that it should be from at most one hour ago.

How can I do it in mongoose?

Currently this is my code:

```
User.findOne({
  resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
  resetPasswordExpires: ... // missing this part
}
```